# margin-top change based on content height

Tags: html, css

I've got a video that I'm using as a background above the fold on a page, spanning 100% width. I want the video to be situated at *almost* the center point of the page. I figured the best option was to have the height set to something along the lines of using vh. However, I noticed that when I get to larger screens, since the video itself re-sizes to the larger width, it makes the video height larger as well, resulting in the whole bottom being cut off.

This is what I have:

```
    .container {
      position: relative;
      margin-top: 20vh;
    }

    .video {
      opacity: .2;
      width: 100vw;
      vertical-align: middle;
      height: auto;
    }
```

Is there a way to figure out how what the height of the video is, which then I could use to figure out how much padding I can add at the top as blank space? Or is there an even easier method that I'm over-looking?

Thanks!

*Edit to add HTML*
Here's the HTML for comparison:

```
<div class="container">

    <video autoplay muted loop class="video">
      <source src="./media/MockUpVid.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>

</div>
```

Comment: can you post your container and video html, so I can see the relationship?

Comment: @N-ate Added the HTML for reference.

Comment: Can you make the container height like 100vh or something responsive and then absolute position the video 50vh from the bottom (with transform: translateY(50%) or something like that) and just forget the margin-top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: calc((100vh - 56vw)/2);
}

.video {
  opacity: .2;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-height: 60vh;
}
```

Using the aspect ratio we were able to achieve the desired layout.

Comment: It seems that this configuration just sets a single height and changes the width. To go a bit more in depth - I was looking to keep the width 100%, I like it spanning the whole distance of the landing page. But I want there to be white space above the video. The issue is, if I set the margin to, say, 20vh, it works on small screens, but when the screen gets larger, the video itself gets wider (and taller), and it cuts off the bottom. So I was hoping to have it find how high the video was, and set the top margin based on that number, so that the whole video is still visible.

Comment: Do you know the aspect ratio? Then we can make a good solution.

Comment: Good call! It's a 16:9 aspect ratio.

Comment: Sorry! Got called away by my boss. If you want to edit my solution to add what you discovered that'd be great!

Comment: No worries! Your aspect ratio suggestion got me thinking and lead to the right solution. Edited to reflect solution, and selected as answer. Thanks so much for the help!